# unable to read trace file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to read the trace file, unfortunately I get the message `...is not a recognizable trace file`.
the query I am using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable('<myLogPath>\Log\log.trc', default)
```

What I have been able to check so far:

1. the message appears because the file is currently in use and cannot be accessed.
2. on the server on which it works properly, in `sys.traces` I have 2 entries:

| id | status | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ...\Log\myLog_381.trc |
| 2 | 0 | NULL |

on the server on which it does not work, I have only one entry:

| id | status | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ...\Log\Log_890.trc |

3. i tried stopping and restarting (`EXEC sp_configure 'default trace enabled'`; a new .trc file was created), but still the second entry is missing and it seems to be crucial, because the first one will always be blocked anyway.
4. manually creating a new trace requires a path to be specified, and as you can see on the running server there is NULL so this must have been created by the system?

Comment: The second entry with the `NULL` path is unrelated to your problem. It is a different trace that is currently stopped according to the status. Most likely a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange, you should always be able to read the trace file, as long as you have rights to it that is.

I usually do it this way:

```sql
select x.*
from sys.traces t
cross apply ::fn_trace_gettable(path, null) x
```

This reads all the traces that are running.